Creating polygons with hole instead of overlapping polygons when using contour tool in QGIS
In QGIS 3.40 I used the 'Contours' tool from a Raster; this generates polylines. I convert these polylines into polygons using the 'Lines to Polygons' tool. The generated polygons overlap, and I want the 'small interior polygons' to punch holes in the 'large exterior polygons' to create 'hole-punched polygons'.
I tried the 'Difference' tool and the 'Symmetrical Difference' tool, but neither works...
Here is a screenshot of my polygon layer, represented with 50% opacity to show the overlapping;

I've added this screenshot following the answer from @CyrilMikhalchenko


You are asking a wrong question. Read to documentation of the gdal_contour utility that QGIS is using in the background https://gdal.org/en/latest/programs/gdal_contour.html.

-p Generate contour polygons rather than contour lines.

Open the "Advanced parameters" section in QGIS, write -p into the "Additional command-line parameters" box and you will get not-overlapping polygons directly.

Thank you for your response. It indeed provides a solution for the proper use of the 'Contours' tool. However, the other part of my question remains unanswered: how can we 'hole' the large polygons with the 'small' ones to create 'polygons with holes' (in other words, 'donuts')... I mean in general, not just for the 'Contours' tool case.

I dont understand what you want. Contour polygons does not overlap eachother. You can extract the polygons/donuts you want for example by attribute. For some generalized method of dealing with overlaps you can look in to Union

@A.Jean wants to know how to do it generally. ST_Difference as in PostGIS https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Difference.html and other libraries does a donut from  two geometries, but in the screenshot there are 4 polygons piled up. It is an interesting problem theoretically how to run the pairwise differences for all geometries with a single operation, or if it is even possible generally. In this countour case it could be possible to sort the polygons by area and compute (biggest - second biggest), (second biggest - third biggest) etc.

So, if I understood the translation of the text correctly and saw the answer in your figure, how about using the tool called <Build Polygons> on the outline layer, with the active checkbox <Save Linear Layer Table Structure [optional]> as shown in the figure below.

Figure
So let's get on with it,

input geodata: layer type - polygon, with the name - relief_test, with overlapping polygonal objects, as shown in the figure below.


Figure

Create a virtual layer, then add your layer using the “Import” button, then copy and paste the SQL query into the “Query” field as shown in the image below.


Figure

Run the query for execution.

SELECT ST_Polygonize(geometry) geometry FROM (SELECT ST_Boundary(geometry) geometry FROM relief_test) foo


The result of the query execution: a virtual layer, with hole polygons, as shown in the figure below.


Figure

Save the virtual layer to the desired file with the extension...

The SQL query is called ST_OverlappingPolygons_PolygonsWithHoles.
CM-FOGS

Thanks for your answer, it helps. I didn't know the difference between the two tools that aims at creating polygons from lines ... (cf. image). However, the other part of my question remains unsolved : how can we 'hole' large polygons with 'small' ones to create 'polygons with holes' (in other words, 'donuts') when they are initially overlapping ...

To "flatten" overlapping polygons you might look at:

running SAGA polygon self-intersection and then selecting and deleting polygons with the pipe symbol in your contour field
Running the GRASS v.clean (break, snap, bpol) and then running the delete duplicate geometries tool.

